# wp8.1 html5 app autoscroll to focused input

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mobile, windows-phone-8

When I'm focusing on  element by clicking it or by jQuery focus() method the page autoscrolls to it by both axises. But I need scrolling only by y-axis. How can I do this?

This is my page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgIU2.png

This is the page with focused input:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n08r.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try target the whole div (or container) element first with an id..

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#divorContainer [name='yourInput']").focus();
});
```

and just be sure the container element uses the total width of the page.